# Itune store operation failed

Tags: xcode, xcode6

i have an issue when i upload my app to the iTune store. so it give me the

following error .. so please help me. i have added this two images for detail.

i have also search a lot but not solved my question.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please click your project > Daily Water Alert (as opposed to Target > Daily Water Alert). What does it say there under "Valid Architectures" ?

Comment: There is not arm64 under your "Architectures" setting (In your second screenshot). It should say `Standard Architectures (armv7, arm64) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD)`. Please ensure this under both project > Daily Water Alert as well as Target > Daily Water Alert

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your build settings to look like this:

[image: Standard Architectures]

Comment: If you compiled CorePlot in a separate target, you need to also set it to compile for standard architectures (so you can pick up the 64 bit compiled code).

Comment: All of those missing symbols in the screenshot you attempted to add into my answer were for CorePlot.  You need to make sure CorePlot also compiles for 64-bit code as well.  How do you include CorePlot in your app?  As a static library, framework, or do you include the source files directly into your project?

Comment: no i have a framework added to my coreproject   CorePlot.framework

Comment: You need to compile that framework to have 64-bit code as well.